# nodes and links out of sync in d3 v4 force simulation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dynamic, simulation

After dynamically updating the data for a force simulation in d3, the node's g element is initialized in a different place than where the links point to, and they do not move in sync when I drag them.
[Here is what the graph looks like after adding a node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lXeV.png).

I followed this tutorial for the update pattern: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795.

I create my links and nodes like so:

```
 // build the arrow

svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
 .data(["end"])      // different link/path types can be defined here
 .enter().append("svg:marker")    // this section adds in the arrows
 .attr("id", String)
 .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
 .attr("refX", 15)
 .attr("refY", -1.5)
 .attr("markerWidth", 6)
 .attr("markerHeight", 6)
 .attr("orient", "auto")
 .append("svg:path")
 .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

// create the link drawing

var link = svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "links")
   .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")
 .selectAll("line")
 .data(graph.links)
 .enter()
    .append("line")
  .attr("stroke-width", "4px");

// node is a group element
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
.data(graph.nodes, function (d) { return d.id; })
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "node")
      .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended));

// add circle to the node

node
.append("circle")
   .attr("r", function (d) { return d.id == undefined ? 0 : d.width / 2 + 2 * padding; })
   .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.type); })
    .attr('stroke', '#000000')
    .attr('stroke-width', '3');


// add the text to the group 

node
.append('text')
.text(node => node.type)
  .attr('font-size', 15)
  .attr('font-family', fontFamily)
  .attr('dx', function (d) { return -d.width / 2 })
  .attr('dy', 4);
```

and update the graph when the node and link data is changed like so:

```
           // update graph for nodes
            node = node.data(graph.nodes, function (d) { return d.id; });

            node.exit().remove();

            node = node.enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", dragstarted)
            .on("drag", dragged)
            .on("end", dragended))
            .merge(node);

            node
            .append("circle")
            .attr("r", function (d) { return d.id == undefined ? 0 : d.width / 2 + 2 * padding; })
            .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.type); })
            .attr('stroke', '#000000')
            .attr('stroke-width', '3');
            console.log(graph.nodes);

            // add the text to the group
            node
           .append('text')
           .text(node => node.type)
             .attr('font-size', 15)
             .attr('font-family', fontFamily)
             .attr('dx', function (d) { return -d.width / 2 })
             .attr('dy', 4);

            // update links
            link = link.data(graph.links);
            link.exit().remove();

            link = link.enter()
             .append("line")
             .attr("stroke-width", "4px")
             .merge(link);


            // restart simulation
            simulation.nodes(graph.nodes);
            simulation.force("link").links(graph.links);
            simulation.alpha(0.01);
            simulation.restart();
```